# react useState working unexpectedly with inputs

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'

const Upload = () => {
    const [song, setSong] = useState({
        title: '',
        audio_file: '',
        genre: '',
    })

    const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null)

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSong({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    const handleAudio = (e) => {
        setAudio(e.target.files[0])
        setSong({audio_file: audio})
    }

    const uploadSong = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(song.title, song.audio_file, song.genre)
    }

    return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={uploadSong}>
            <section className="upload">
                <div className="upload-content">
                    <h4>Upload Music</h4>
                    <input type="file" name="music" id='song' className='hidden'  onChange={handleAudio}/>
                    <label for='song' className='btn'>Select Music</label>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section className="info">
                <div className="info-content">
                    <h2>Upload Info</h2>
                    <div className="info-visual">
                        <div className="info-single">
                            <p>Audio File</p>
                            {audio ? audio.name : <i className='fas fa-times' />}
                        </div>

                        <div className="info-single">
                            <p>Title {song.title ? 'checked' : 'not checked' }</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Title..." name='title' onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="info-single">
                            <p>Size</p>
                            {audio ? `${(audio.size / 1000000).toString().substr(0,3)} MB` : <i className='fas fa-times' />}
                        </div>

                        <div className="info-single">
                            <p>Genre {song.genre ? 'checked' : 'not checked'}</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Genre..." name='genre' onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </div>
                        {song.title && song.audio_file && song.genre ? 
                        <button className="btn" type='submit'>Continue</button> : <button className="btn">Please fill in the fields</button>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </form>
    </>
    )
}

export default Upload
```

> Basically, both title and genre are 'not checked' and when I type in title it becomes 'checked' and when I type in genre it becomes 'checked' but title becomes 'not checked'... how so? I tried doing song.title.length > 0 but react throws an error and says song.title is undefined, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting entire `song` state in the `handleChange` function, whereas you only want to overwrite a specific field within the state object. Appropriate way to achieve your goal is to:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const newState = { ...song, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
  setSong(newState);
}
```